# Can't dismiss modal and change page location

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-strap

I am using Angular-Strap to provide my modals and I am having an issue with dismissing the modal and then navigating to another page. For some reason I can only dismiss the modal if I am not using $location.path and once I add it then it dismisses the modal itself and navigates to a new page but the grey background still sticks around. I was looking for call backs but I have not figured out a way to do these 2 actions together.

modal call

```
var modal = $modal({
            template: '/Product/Delete',
            persist: true,
            show: false,
            backdrop: 'static',
            scope: $scope
        });
```

call to open the modal

```
$scope.confirmDeleteProduct = function () {
            $q.when(modal).then(function (modalEl) {
                modalEl.modal('show');
            });
        };
```

call made when they hit delete on the modal

```
$scope.deleteProduct = function (id,dismiss) {
            //ProductSvc.deleteProduct(id).success(function ($resp) {
            dismiss();
            //$scope.hideDeleteModal = true;
            $location.path('product/');

            //});
            //$scope.products = _.without($scope.products, product);
        };
```

delete modal

```
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">x</button>
            <h4>Delete Product</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Do you really want to delete the product <strong>{{product.Name}}</strong>?</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn" ng-click="dismiss()">Cancel</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="deleteProduct(product.Id,dismiss);">Delete</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8):

I've been having the exact same problem Tony.  Now, this feels dirty, but I noticed that after  calling $(modal).modal('hide') -- or toggle -- that the .modal-backdrop stays on the screen after location changes.  So, I did this:

```
$('#cancelModal').modal('toggle');
$('.modal-backdrop').remove();
$location.path('/');
```

Several similar posts suggest using angular-strap or angular-ui bootstrap, but I don't want to go in either of those directions right now.

EDIT:  [UI-bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)

Comment: I ended up taking a different approach but I still plan on using it at another point, I will give it a try and if it works out come back and mark this answered. Appreciate your response :D

Comment: what approach did you take?

Comment: I was testing out different front end experiences, I ended up taking a different approach on the front end. Bounced around from MVC -> pure AngularJS/WebAPI -> AngularJS & MVC -> MVC & WebApi & sprinkled AngularJS. Not to the point where i have needed the modal yet though. I was testing crud screens out, now I am actually working on the real apps structure.

Comment: I ended up falling back to ui-bootstrap for angularizing TWBS behaviours, works fairly well.  I'm typically using modals for the CRUD Delete use case.

Comment: Yeah that is exactly what I needed it for. Are you using both angular-strap and ui-bootstrap? I read you could mix and match but I felt it could make things kinda fragile in the sense of future maintenance.

Comment: no, I found angular-strap to be broken in angular 1.2 with twbs3.  I just use ui-bs.

Answer (score 0):

I was also having this issue.  If you are using angular bootstrap 0.13.0 try downgrading to 0.12.1.  This resolved the issue for me.

The cause is an appears to be an incompatability with ngAnimate 1.4.2 https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/3633